# Why can I assign List<dynamic> to a List<String>?

Tags: dart

I am getting confused around how the type checking works for dart. As shown, assigning a general `List<dynamic>` to a `List<String>` is OK. That essentially means I can assign any content in that list, not just `String`. Why is that?

```dart
void main() {
  List<String> a;
  a = [1];                 // pass
  a = new List<int>();     // fail
  a = 1;                   // fail
  a = new List<String>();  // pass
  a.add(1);                // fail
}
```

Comment: Declaration and re-definition shouldn't be referring different signature/data type.
Even if you use dynamic, it should contain same type content, you cannot merge multiple data type contents to list instance. You can use ArrayList If you want to have multi type data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dynamic` type is special. It really means "turn off all type checking for this, I know what I'm doing".

In your example, you assign a `List<dynamic>` instance to a `List<String>` variable. The static type checker sees: List to list, that's ok, and the type parameter is dynamic, so I'll just not check that at all, the programmer must know that he is doing.

Whenever you use `dynamic` as a type, or as part of a type, you are taking full responsibility for the typing being correct. The system will let you do whatever you want.

Even without `dynamic`, the Dart type system isn't *safe*. That means that you can create programs with no static type warnings which still fail with a type error at runtime.
Most languages have that problem, actually, as soon as they contain parameterized types with either co- or contra-variant subtyping. Or casts.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. I didn't see that dynamic implies no type checking. If I instead try to assign `List<Object>` to a `List<String>`, then the static type checker complains, as I want. The distinction between `Object` and `dynamic` has confused me.

Comment: @tusj Here's a good read on the subject: https://www.dartlang.org/articles/optional-types/